# Pattern to keep implementation synchronized

Tags: c++, caching, design-patterns, synchronization

In my 3D drawing system, I have two classes: a model class which represents 3D models which have been imported with third party libraries, and a model cache class which represents the data of the model to be serialised into a binary cache (which contains some extra information that I need as well).

The problem I am currently solving is cache invalidation. Given that the model file has been modified after the cache file, I am checking whether the meshes or the scene graph (node structure) has been changed from the cache. The class which checks whether the cache data is valid/invalid, calculates hashes for both the newly imported model and the cache data.

The issue is, if for some reason the implementation of the cache data invalidation changes (i.e. if I decide to include some extra data in the hashing process), then these changes have to be reflected in the model hashing as well.

As I am currently working with multiple people in this project, there's a chance that someone could break this part of the code by making changes in the future. Is there a design pattern which could keep the hashing for both cache and model synchronised, or maybe make it **obvious** that you must make sure to change both parts of the invalidation (cache and model).

The implementation of all of this is in C++, and this is purely a theoretical question as I feel like I have come across this a few times before.

Comment: If both model and cache use the same single hash function doesn't it mean that they are synchronized? In other words, the validation logic should be a part for single class/function and not distributed among your system modules.

Comment: They do use the same hash function yes, but the way each of them is stored in memory is different. So essentially, in the validation class I have a function to hash meshes from the cache, and another to hash meshes from the model. This is where the problem lies I guess.

Comment: I think you should design it in the way that the Mesh is not dependent from how it's stored. In validation class you should have a **single** validation function that gets a mesh as parameter and validates it. In other words you should separate your interfaces from the implementation details (how mesh is stored, etc.).

Comment: @vahancho I see, perhaps both the cache classes and the mesh should inherit from a common interface, then the parameters taken for the validation should be of that common interface. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Maybe. But I would do it so: 1) a base class for all Meshes 2) Sub classes for specific meshes, like meshes from cache and meshes from models, 3) Validation class with single function that gets a pointer to the base Mesh class.

Comment: I see, makes sense. I will have to change my current structure to something like this then, seems like the most reasonable way to ensure this type of problem is not there. @vahancho

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encapsulate the caching behavior. This can be achieved by using composition (composition over inheritance to provide a natural data structure and convenient usage). This way a `Model` is tightly coupled to a `ModelCache`. You can encapsulate the cache operations and move them to common base class. This will enforce that all sub types use the same cache operations or caching behavior:

```
class 3dDrawingModelBase
{
  private:
    DrawingModelCache* modelCache;

  public:   
    3dDrawingModelBase(DrawingModelCache cache) : modelCache(cache) {}

    void invalidateCache() 
    {
      // Cache invalidation implementation
    }  

    BinaryDrawingModelCache serializeToBinaryCache() 
    {
      return this.modelCache.Serialize();
    } 

    size_t toHashCode() 
    {
      // hashing implementation
      // also uses this.modelCache.ToHashCode()
    }   

    list<mesh> getMeshes()
    {
      // return underlying meshes
    }


    void addMesh(Mesh mesh)
    {
      // return underlying meshes
    }
};
```

The cache abstraction:

```
class DrawingModelCache
{
  public:   
    virtual void ToHashCode() = 0; 
    virtual BinaryDrawingModelCache Serialize() = 0;

    list<mesh> getMeshes()
    {
      // return underlying meshes
    }


    void addMesh(Mesh mesh)
    {
      // return underlying meshes
    }
};
```

Now there is only one place where you have to implement the modifications. Since all models must implement `3dDrawingModelBase`, the changes will reflect to all implementations in the whole application. Your team members would automatically use the modified version. As long as you don't introduce new (abstract) members to the base classes and only modify underlying behavior, the modification won't be breaking changes.